# Using VB.net with Excel - How do I MOVE a Page Break?

Tags: excel, vba, vb.net

I started to type a lengthy post but decided to get straight to the question. How do I MOVE a page break in Excel 2021? I have PCs with different versions of Office. Office 2021 seems to **require** a vba SET statement like

`Set ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks(1).Location = Range("A69")`

How can I do that in VB.net?

ALSO.. If I omit 'SET', the formatting is only completed properly in Excel 2021 when I place a debug break at this line, step through it, and run the rest of the code. If I remove the break or compile and run, the formatting is messed up!

Comment: The `Location` property doesn't say that its read only, but I am also getting an error whenever I attempt to give it a new range. Very suspicious. But you can reset it by doing `Activesheet.ResetAllPageBreaks` and then `Activesheet.HPageBreaks.Add YourNewRangeHere`

Comment: Are you in Page Break Preview mode when trying to set the location? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.hpagebreak.location#:~:text=Note%20that%20you%20must%20be%20in%20Page%20Break%20Preview%20mode%20in%20order%20to%20set%20it.

Comment: I am already resetting the page breaks which leaves me with a default page break that I must MOVE. I have also tried adding a new break, but I still need to move the default break. And Yes. I am in Page Break Preview mode.